# How to condense text cleaning steps into single Python function?

Tags: python, performance, function

Newer programmer here, deeply appreciate any help this knowledgeable community is willing to provide.

I have a column of 140,000 text strings (company names) in a pandas dataframe on which I want to strip all whitespace everywhere in/around the strings, remove all punctuation, substitute specific substrings, and uniformly transform to lowercase. I want to then take the first 0:10 elements in the strings and store them in a new dataframe column.

Here is a reproducible example.

```
import string
import pandas as pd

data = ["West Georgia Co", 
        "W.B. Carell Clockmakers", 
        "Spine & Orthopedic LLC",
        "LRHS Saint Jose's Grocery",
        "Optitech@NYCityScape"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['co_name'])

def remove_punctuations(text):
    for punctuation in string.punctuation:
        text = text.replace(punctuation, '')
    return text

# applying remove_punctuations function
df['co_name_transform'] = df['co_name'].apply(remove_punctuations)
# this next step replaces 'Saint' with 'st' to standardize,
# and I may want to make other substitutions but this is a common one.
df['co_name_transform'] = df.co_name_transform.str.replace('Saint', 'st')
# replace whitespace
df['co_name_transform'] = df.co_name_transform.str.replace(' ', '')
# make lowercase
df['co_name_transform'] = df.co_name_transform.str.lower()
# select first 0:10 of strings
df['co_name_transform'] = df.co_name_transform.str[0:10]

print(df)
```

```
                     co_name        co_name_transform
0            West Georgia Co               westgeorgi
1    W.B. Carell Clockmakers               wbcarellcl
2     Spine & Orthopedic LLC               spineortho
3  LRHS Saint Jose's Grocery               lrhsstjose
4       Optitech@NYCityScape               optitechny
```

How can I put all these steps into a single function like this?

```
def clean_text(df[col]):
    for co in co_name:
        do_all_the_steps
    return df[new_col]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function to do this. Try the following one-liner.

```
df['co_name_transform'] = df['co_name'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9-]+', '').str.replace('Saint', 'st').str.lower().str[0:10]
```

Final output will be.

```
                     co_name co_name_transform
0            West Georgia Co        westgeorgi
1    W.B. Carell Clockmakers        wbcarellcl
2     Spine & Orthopedic LLC        spineortho
3  LRHS Saint Jose's Grocery        lrhsstjose
4       Optitech@NYCityScape        optitechny
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the steps in the function you pass to the `apply` method:

```
import re
df['co_name_transform'] = df['co_name'].apply(lambda s: re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s).replace('Saint', 'st').lower()[:10])
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, tried this but seems to strip all text and leave punctuation. How can I tweak it?

Comment: Just fixed it. Can you try it again?

Comment: Thank you, works great, appreciate seeing the methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, similar to the previous one, but with the list of "to_replace" in one dictionary, so you can add more items to replace. Also, the previous solution won't give the first 10.

```
data = ["West Georgia Co", 
        "W.B. Carell Clockmakers", 
        "Spine & Orthopedic LLC",
        "LRHS Saint Jose's Grocery",
        "Optitech@NYCityScape","Optitech@NYCityScape","Optitech@NYCityScape","Optitech@NYCityScape","Optitech@NYCityScape","Optitech@NYCityScape","Optitech@NYCityScape","Optitech@NYCityScape","Optitech@NYCityScape"]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['co_name'])

    to_replace = {'[^A-Za-z0-9-]+':'','Saint':'st'}

    for i in to_replace : 
        df['co_name'] =  df['co_name'].str.replace(i,to_replace[i]).str.lower()
    df['co_name'][0:10]
```

Result :

```
0            westgeorgiaco
1      wbcarellclockmakers
2       spineorthopedicllc
3    lrhssaintjosesgrocery
4      optitechnycityscape
5      optitechnycityscape
6      optitechnycityscape
7      optitechnycityscape
8      optitechnycityscape
9      optitechnycityscape
Name: co_name, dtype: object
```

Previous solution ( won't show the first 10)

```
df['co_name_transform'] = df['co_name'].str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9-]+', '').str.replace('Saint', 'st').str.lower().str[0:10]
```

Result :

```
0     westgeorgi
1     wbcarellcl
2     spineortho
3     lrhssaintj
4     optitechny
5     optitechny
6     optitechny
7     optitechny
8     optitechny
9     optitechny
10    optitechny
11    optitechny
12    optitechny
Name: co_name_transform, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that this creates a container in which I can place other substitution clauses